# "Doing" sport vs studying

Tags: grammar

What is the correct verb in terms of doing some kind of sport? Can I say “do”?
**For example:**
`I want to do free diving` - is this correct? Seems so, but sounds not very well.
**Or is it:**
`I want to study free diving`? But this has a slightly different meaning, studying is not the same as doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say "I want to *go* free diving" or perhaps "I want to *try* free diving" if you've not done it before and just want to see what it is like.

"I want to *study* free diving" would suggest you want to study other people free diving, if you want to learn how to free dive you would say "I want to *learn to* free *dive*" instead.

"I want to *do* free diving" would be understood but sounds clumsy.

---

More generally, the correct verb depends on the sport. You would say "I want to *play* football" and the same applies to all other team sports I can think of. Diving, climbing, and other similar activities use *go* as doing skiing, snowboarding, and skateboarding.

Answer (score 0):

Using "do" with a sport suggests a school situation where sports or other activities are treated like subjects. In such a context a student would do free diving, or do football, or do swimming, or do science. In a normal context one would go free diving, or play football, or swim, or study science.